# Audio mixer on battery power

Tags: audio, dc-dc-converter, mixer

I have an audio mixer which can run on two 9V batteries in series.  I'd like to run it off a single 12V supply.

- Can I use two 12V-9V DC-DC converters both running off a 12V battery?
- Will the connection to the 12V battery short the 9V series connection?

The [mixer is a Behringer 1002b,](https://www.behringer.com/product.html?modelCode=P0A04) the AC input adapter is 16V and 3V.

When I test with batteries I get 18V across the power switch

Comment: You haven't supplied enough information. (1) Are the batteries arranged as an 18 V battery pack or is there a wire from the centre to give +9 / -9 V supply? (2) Is there an AC adaptor input and, if so, what is the voltage specification? (3) Does the mixer have a name, model and a user manual that you can link to? Please [edit] to include all the information in your question (and not in the comments).

Comment: It's highly likely that this uses two batteries to crudely achieve positive and negative suppliers for older op-amps.  You cannot use non-isolated converters running from the same supply for this.  There are positive to negative converters however.

Comment: Whatever you try to do is likely more expensive then getting the ac adapter. Are you trying to make this portable? From what type of battery (car/bike/etc?)

Comment: I have ac adaptor, mixer is new. I'm wanting to extend usable time ( currently 4 hrs on battery) 12v battery maybe 7Ah

Comment: Probably not. It has two isolated 18 Vac supplies to create +-15 Vdc. You can use a DC/DC to generate a negative one or connect yourself from + to - rail with twice the voltage if you have a servo (or other mean to clamp) to force the GND in the middle.

Comment: You've linked to an ad page for the mixer. We need the user manual.

Comment: https://mediadl.musictribe.com/media/sys_master/h8e/h7d/8850123227166.pdf  It says 3 batteries but the third is for phantom Mic power which I dont need

Comment: Would Lithium non-rechargeable 9V batteries instead of Alkaline be an option? They have twice the capacity. Anyway, I think that if you want to use a large external battery, you will be better of trying to "emulate" the outputs of the AC adapter than trying to connect to the internal battery connections.

Comment: Because the mixer needs both positive and negative supplies, it's simpler to use 2 batteries. You *could* generate a false ground from a single battery easily but there are 'watchas'. Is the suggested 12V battery your car battery for example ? More info is needed.

Comment: Its a larger 12V battery. Probably a 7Ah sealed lead acid type. I'll get two and drop the voltage down to 9V. Easiest option.