# How can I make a 9V 1A DC adaptor to power this audio mixer?

Tags: batteries

I have an audio mixer that is powered by electricity from the wall socket, but I'd really like to power it on batteries instead for greater mobility.

I could not find any ready solution to purchase online so I believe I'll need to DIY it. I am not great with electricity but I know it is possible to connect power sources in parallel or series in order to control the voltage and amperage.

The power input required is only **9V 1A**.

Here's some pictures from the power adapter: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnlUn.jpg

[image]

[image]

[image]

How could I achieve what I want? Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: 1 12 volt truck battery and a dc to dc converter - should run for hours.

Comment: Talk to this guy https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/525649/audio-mixer-on-battery-power

Comment: The search term you want is "9v power bank". Make sure to find one with a 9 V DC output.

Comment: @BrianDrummond similar goal, but this very different practically.  That one needs positive and negative supplies for classic op-amps, this just needs 9 volts DC.

Comment: The conceptually simplest DIY approach where would be something like a 12 volt "gel cell" and a 9 volt regulator module.  If one understand the internals of the mixer, it is likely it can tolerate a *range* of voltages making something like a number of AA cells (which would vary in voltage as they discharge) workable, but without gaining an understanding of the internal circuitry, that is risky.  If you are looking to simply purchase a solution, that is off topic here - for such a query you'd do better on an audio forum.

Comment: Given a mixer is of no use on its own, you should probably consider the overall power needs for your entire setup, and not simply the mixer by itself.  Possibly there are better solutions for the mixing job in a compact battery powered setup.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Actually you are perfectly right, but the questioner probably has seen that battery power for the mixer is just what he needs. It's not at all uncommon that a 2...3 person group has a common already battery operated mono or stereo amp which has only 2...3  inputs - one for mic and 1...2  for something else. A small mixer makes possible to have a mic for everyone, an amplified synth and a backing track player.  The mixer can in this case be the only non-battery powered device.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be asking for a (rechargeable) battery power pack for mobile use.

Note that your mixer is highly unlikely to draw 1A from it's power inlet. I'd measure the current draw. It'll most likely be less than 100mA. The 1A A.C. supply is simply used for convenience. There's little demand for 1 watt AC adaptors.

Similarly, it's unlikely that *exactly 9* volts is required. So that the power pack is still useful until exhausted, I'd go for a 12V power pack when freshly charged.

Another possibility is qty 3 18650 Li-ion batteries. Again 2500mAh is a common capacity for these.

So, what batteries to use ? A bunch of NiMH AA batteries in series may be practical. The open circuit voltage of NiMH is ~ 1.3V. 10 in series gives 13V when fresh, 8 in series gives 10.4V. Your choice. The Ah rating depends on the batteries but 2500mAh is readily available, giving you 25 hours use at 100mA current draw.

You'll find no shortage of holders for AA batteries on ebay for example. You simply need to package them in a suitable enclosure, aka a 'plastic box !

I'd recommend fitting a large electrolytic capacitor 'across' the output btw to ensure low AC output impedance at audio frequencies. Say 4700uF 16V.

A 'low battery' warning LED might be a good idea too. Simple to design. If you want, I'll draw one.

You'll need a charger of course too.

Comment: It would be interesting to me to see the inside of the mixer - namely the power input. In SoHo networking gear nowadays, I'd expect a buck converter, making lower voltage rails - but I have no clue what to expect in a mixer. (The buck converter in SoHo networking equipment actually accepts quite a broad range of input voltages, I'd say 7 to 15 Volts if the box says 9V nominal input.) Also, an SMPS external mains adaptor would likely be pretty noisy... I'd expect a filter on the input. A battery is much better in that respect (cleaner).

Comment: Know what you mean but in inexpensive audio gear, even the decent stuff, any switching regulator is disparaged ! I 'know' Behringer and It'll just be a DC input for sure.

Answer (score 0):

The new and best (imo) solution to this (powering the 9v mixer) is the Joyo 05 pedal power pack, which has a rechargeable lithium ion battery, and a number of 9v outputs at both 100 ma and 300 ma, plus a 5v usb charger at one amp. The Joyo 05 also has one switchable 12v / 18v output which gives out only 100 ma (worthless for anything), and of the two units I have, only one actually gives 12v, so don't count on that feature, but the 9v battery power is great and runs for hours. In the case of the OP's mixer, there is some chance that the 300 ma output of the Joyo will not be enough, but an electronics tech should be able to measure the requirement of the mixer if it is not in the specs. In this case, it may be that the mixer will run fine on low amperage if the volume is kept low.